# How do I read ImageDescription w/PIL (or exifread)? (Update)

Tags: python-imaging-library, photoshop, exif

I am specifically trying to read `ImageDescription` from images that come out of a particular workflow that involves Photoshop.

With PIL, it looks like I can read all the EXIF data that was written by the camera:

```
...
('ISOSpeedRatings', 200)
('Make', u'Canon')
('MaxApertureValue', (175, 100))
('MeteringMode', 5)
('Model', u'Canon EOS 5D Mark II')
('Orientation', 1)
('ResolutionUnit', 2)
('SceneCaptureType', 0)
...
```

and some by Photoshop (assuming `Artist` isn't a camera setting):

```
('Artist', u'N***** S*****')
('Software', u'Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 Macintosh')
```

but, I cannot see the description.

I've checked PIL's `ExifTags` `TAGS` dict and can see that PIL can parse that field:

```
...
269 DocumentName
270 ImageDescription  <--
271 Make
...
```

I've tried the same with [exifread](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/blob/develop/exifread/tags/exif.py) and have gotten the same result: looks like it should be able to parse `ImageDescription`, but doesn't actually parse it.

I read on [the EXIF spec](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html%20Metadata%20reference%20tables) that 2-bytes code (unicode?) should not be written to `ImageDescription`.  Could that be it?

What am I missing?

**Update 1: '16/Apr/18 - 12:29 PST**
Looks like it's a caption that's stored in the XMP structure.  Probably going to close this question, soon.

Answer (score 0):

The information in these images is being stored in the XMP format.

I used this nice online image parsing tool to see where the description was coming from:
http://regex.info/exif.cgi